# Layout with buttons inside Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, button, layout, background

I want to put a Layout with Buttons inside Google Maps with a gradient background as in this app:

[image]

i have done many combinations but they not works. How I can to make it?

Answer (score 1):

it just put a  maps and button inside relative layout it works for me

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_for_welcome"
    android:apiKey="@string/live_key_for_map"
    android:clickable="true" >
</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
  <LinerLayout
    android:id="@+id/textView_for_welcome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"

    android:background="@drawable/backgroud_layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
       ----inside put all ur Views ---- 
</LinerLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

also use gradient background for button (or any layout) u want but important thing is u must specify next to map

You can use backgroud_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#AA474946"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:angle="270"/>
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

to drawable folder 
use FF-Alpha FF-Red FF-blue FF-Green

Comment: where I put gradient background for layout of buttons?

Comment: android:background="#AAFF4a4a"

Comment: please check my latesest answer